# What type of error are missing diacritics?

Tags: diacritics

What type of error are missing diacritics?

Spelling error? Ortographic error? Something else?

Comment: See the [encyclopedia article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf). And don't be sure there are clearly-delimited types of errors covering everything you can think of.

Answer (score 2):

"Orthography" is simply the rules of writing a language, so it's not particularly distinct from "spelling".

If you wanted to draw a line between them, you could say that "spelling" is specifically the sequence of characters making up the word, while "orthography" also encompasses the details of individual characters, so that writing the letter N backwards is an orthographic mistake but not a spelling one. In this case, missing diacritics would be a spelling mistake only if letters with diacritics are considered separate letters of the alphabet (as in Polish, but not in French).